# WebStorm - Using Spread Operator Returns: error TS2488: Type '{}' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, webstorm

I am experiencing this annoying TypeScript error:

> error TS2488: Type '{}' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.

As you can see in my code I am using the spread operator. After some researches I have found that I had to update my`tsconfig.json` with `"target": "es6"` but nothing changed. What am I missing?

**Function**

```
 formatFileName(e) {
    let files = e.target.files;
    this.test = Array.from(files).reduce((acc, cur) => [
        ...acc, {
            name: cur.name.replace(/^.*\\/, "")
        }
    ], [])
 }
```

**TS CONFIG**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
        "es2017",
        "dom"
    ]
   }
 }
```

**TS CONFIG APP (if it helps)**

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": [],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es6",
  },
 "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can't  reproduce your issue with the `tsconfig` you provided

Comment: So you mean that the problem is not in my tsconfig? Maybe is Webstorm that I am using?

Comment: Not sure where the problem is .. I would try to run the compiler outside the IDE to see if it's an IDE problem. I used your tsconfigs in VSCode, it seems to work

Comment: Ok, I have updated the question indicating that it may caused by Webstorm. I'll try your suggestion too, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. I noticed that in 'lib' tsconfig.json file "es2015" wasn't indicated (as suggested in[this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12707#issuecomment-265518894) answer), but that, for some reason, didn't change anything.

So I went up to the function 'formatFileName(e)' and assigned to this.test the array of files, and just after this declaration I applied the reduce function to do my operations.

**FIXED FUNCTION**

```
 formatFileName(e) {
    let files = e.target.files;
    this.test = Array.from(files)
    this.test.reduce((acc, cur) => [
        ...acc, {
            name: cur.name.replace(/^.*\\/, "")
        }
    ], [])
}
```